# Dokku/Docker, how to access file in file system of running container?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker, dokku

Previously, to access a file in a running dokku instance I would run: 
`docker ps` to get the container ID followed by
`ls /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<container-id>/app/...`
note: I'm just using 'ls' as an example command. I ultimately want to reference a particular file.

This must have changed, as the container ID is no longer accessible via this path. There are loads of dirs in that folder, but none that match any of the running containers.

It seems like mounting a volume for the entire container would be overkill in this scenario. I know I can access the file system using `dokku run project-name ls`, and also `docker exec <container-id> ls`, but neither of those will satisfy my use case.

To explain a bit more fully, in my dokku project, I have some .sql files that I'm using to bootstrap my postgres DB. These files get pushed up via `git push` with the rest of the project.

I'm hoping to use the postgres dokku plugin to run the following:

`dokku postgres:connect db-name < file-name.sql`

This is what I had previously been doing using:

`dokku postgres:connect db-name < /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<container-id>/app/file-name.sql` but that no longer works.

Any thoughts on this? Am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks very much for any thoughts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example:

`dokku apps:list`

=====> My Apps

DummyApp

`dokku enter DummyApp`

Enter bash to the DummyApp container.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer... it's so straightforward to just be dropped into a shell in your app's working directory.

Answer (score 2):

Never rely on the `/var/lib/docker` file system paths as most of the data stored there is dependent on the [storage driver currently in use](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/) so it is subject to change.

`cat` the file from an existing container

```bash
docker exec <container> cat file.sql | dokku postgres:connect db-name
```

`cat` the file from an image

```bash
docker run --rm <image> cat file.sql | dokku postgres:connect db-name
```

Copy file from an existing container

```bash
docker cp <container>:file.sql file.sql
dokku postgres:connect db-name < file.sql
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. This makes so much sense. My unix experience, is obviously limited. Your explanation helped me better understand exactly what the `dokku postgres:connect db-name < file-name.sql` command was doing. Thanks for explaining how to get that file output into my dokku command. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. Unix command line is [all about the pipes](http://www.linfo.org/pipe.html) and [redirection](http://www.linfo.org/redirection.html). `<` just redirects a file to the standard input of a command.

Comment: How to get the container ID of a Dokku container?